# JMS Message Selector implementation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

I need to verify whether javax.jms.Message matches provided selector i.e.:

```
Message msg = ...;
SomeSelectorMatcher matcher = new SomeSelectorMatcher(" someProp='someVal' and someProp2 >3 ... ");

if(matcher.matches(msg){
     //do sth
}else{
     //do sth else
}
```

Is there any out of the box library which does that ?

Comment: ALL of the out-of-the-box JMS libraries do that.  If the app sees the message then the selector matched.  If not, then it didn't.  But I get the feeling that the question you really want answered is "how do I figure out why my selectors are not matching specific messages?"  Is that correct or if not, can you clarify the question?

Comment: @marcin-michalski have you figured out a way to do that by chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to implement simple test framework which would simulate JMS behaviour but using synchronous approach. Anyway I was able to find library which has Message Selector parser implemented - http://openjms.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Message selectors are not meant do allow this. Why you whould need this?

I'd recommend to create multiple consumers for it. E.g. from your example above I would create two consumers. One with this code:

```
//do sth
```

and the second for

```
//do sth else
```

The first would have the selector and the second the selector logically opposite.

If you really need to do filtering after you receive the message you can directly compare your headers and properties from the incoming message. You can even process the body while selectors cannot do that.

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnceh.html